# Swift : convert UIImageOrientation to ALAssetOrientation

Tags: ios, enums, swift

I am having trouble with ENUMS, specifically  UIImageOrientation to ALAssetOrientation

I have tried :

```
  var orientation : ALAssetOrientation = image.imageOrientation.toRaw()
```

and

```
  var orientation : ALAssetOrientation = image.imageOrientation as ALAssetOrientation
```

Any idea how this should be done?

Comment: I think `var orientation = ALAssetOrientation.fromRaw(image.imageOrientation.toRaw())` should work.

Comment: [Swift Guide for more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_228)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In swift `enumerations` are `type`.They are not `objective c` or `c` enums.Enums itself declared as `struct` and they are not have their associated values as `Int`.So do not think swift and objective c enums same

Use below code to make the enum instance of `ALAssetOrientation` with `fromRaw`

```
      var orientation : ALAssetOrientation = ALAssetOrientation.fromRaw(UIImage().imageOrientation.toRaw())!
```

As `fromRaw` returns optional in case of it is not valid raw value it returns nil so while assigning you need to `unwrap` it or you can use `var orientation : ALAssetOrientation!` implicit optional

Refer swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

> Use an enumeration’s fromRaw method to try to find an enumeration
>   member with a particular raw value.Not all possible Int values will
>   find a matching planet, however. Because of this, the fromRaw method
>   returns an optional enumeration member.

**EDIT** In Xcode 6.1 use

```
   var orientation : ALAssetOrientation = ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: UIImage().imageOrientation.rawValue)!
```

Comment: This answer is now out of date.

Comment: @m00sey sorry about that.I have edited the answer according to new Xcode.Thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 2):

`fromRaw` has been replace by an initializer for `ALAssetOrientation`

```
ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: image.imageOrientation.rawValue)!
```